# Is there a way to trigger a user account creation from a different CMS?

Tags: plugin-development, users, multi-site, controller, routing

I'm a junior web developer working with Craft CMS.

I was wondering if there was a way to trigger a controller I have for my Craft CMS from an outside CMS. We have more than one website that offers online trainings for people to purchase, but the course itself is hosted on our Craft CMS.

I'm hoping to achieve this:

1. A person purchases a course from our Wordpress site.
2. After successful purchase, it triggers a request to our Craft CMS which creates an account and then enrolls them in the course.

I'm not sure how to go about it...

Appreciate any insight on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the controller endpoint that's also used for public registrations as described in the knowledge base article on [Front-End User Accounts](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/front-end-user-accounts). But instead of providing an HTML form on your site, you're going to trigger the request to the controller endpoint from PHP, probably from a hook in your WordPress site. First, make sure that the setting to *Allow public registration* is on to allow unauthenticated requests to create new accounts.

You can execute the request however you like, here's an example using [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) (might need some adjustments).

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://your-site.com']);

$response = $client->post('actions/users/save-user', [
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => 'alice-foobar',
        'firstName' => 'Alice',
        'lastName' => 'Foobar',
        'email' => 'alice@example.com',
        // …
    ],
]);

$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
```

You're probably gonna need to provide a CSRF token as well. In this case, make a request to [`users/session-info`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-controllers-userscontroller.html#method-actionsessioninfo) first to get a valid token and then pass it back to the POST request.

Using this approach you can perform additional methods like saving user data and adding entries / enrollment information. Note that most controller methods will require authentication. You can also provide a [custom controller endpoint](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/controllers.html) to perform all those steps in one go, implementing whatever authentication method you deem appropriate.